# How to write Amount<Currency> parameter field in Corda?

Tags: corda

I am trying to make a CorDapp that uses Amount and am passing "5" and it does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify it as you would with real cash, try "5.00 USD".